# Translation Languages Python

Tags: python, api, translation

which API can i use to translate text in Python?

I don't want to use Google or Bing. Is there something others?

Google keeps saying "Day limit exceed" and Bing translates first 3-4 questions and then i've got *"Cannot find an active Azure Market Place Translator Subscription associated with the request credentials"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this script if you want to check it: https://github.com/mouuff/Google-Translate-API : )

very easy to use:

```
to_translate = 'Hola como estas?'
print("%s >> %s" % (to_translate, translate(to_translate)))
print("%s >> %s" % (to_translate, translate(to_translate, 'fr')))
```

should print Hola como estas >> Hello how are you

and Hola como estas? >> Bonjour comment allez-vous?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, will accept in 8mins :D

Comment: But my translated text have &quot;

Comment: can you send me the exemple code of what you did